# How do I add an expression into a query?

Tags: 7, database

When I use the code below, I get the following error:

> Call to a member function addExpression() on a non-object

```
 $query = db_select('node', 'n')
    ->fields('n', array('nid'))
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAssoc();
  $query->addExpression('MAX(nid)', 'max_nid');
```

What is wrong with that code?

Comment: You added the addExpression after doing the query. It's not correct. You should add before that.

Comment: Where should  I add the addExpression is it before fields() ? I have read that addExpression cannot be chained?

Comment: After fields(). Can you try the code my answer. The format code in the comment block doesn't look good. So i must input in the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the code to the following one.

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->fields('n', array('nid'));
$query->addExpression('MAX(nid)', 'max_nid');
$query->execute()->fetchAssoc();
```

The value returned from `fetchAssoc()` is an array. Since you are assigning the value returned from `fetchAssoc()` to `$query`, and then calling `$query->addExpression()`, you rightly get the error. You cannot call a method on something that is not an object (in this case, an array).

If you want to list all the node IDs and set *max_nid* to the maximum value, you can use the following code.

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->fields('n', array('nid','type'));
$query->leftJoin('node', 'n1', 'n1.type = n.type');
$query->addExpression('MAX(n1.nid)', 'max_nid');
$query->groupBy('n.nid');
$result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

Comment: I got the following error while trying to use the above code.Call to a member function execute() on a non-object

Comment: Please try again

Comment: Sorry now its working but i am not able to get the value for MAX(nid).Do we need to write something else to get the value

Comment: Please check the update of my answer

Comment: So I would have to write $query->execute()->fetchAssoc(); only at the variable where I need get the data..

Comment: Can you tell me what is your purpose for that SQL sentence?

Comment: Why am I getting a single value when database table contains multiple values for nids ??

Comment: I want to get the all the list of nids and along with that I want to get the max_nid  which are of a specific type ?

Comment: Got it by using fetchAll() i could get the list of all nids..

Comment: Yes you can use the fetchAll. Please check my update in answer for further information. I think it will help.

Comment: The updated answer worked for me.